# An estimation with Bernoulli

Tags: real-analysis

Let $n$ be a positive integer (i.e. $n \geq 1$) and $x \in \mathbf R_{\geq 0}$. I need to show that
$$ \frac{nx^{1/n}}{n e^x + \sin(nx)} \leq \frac{1}{e^x} $$
holds.

I tried looking at the $n$-th power and using Bernoulli's inequality:
$$ \left( \frac{nx^{1/n}}{n e^x + \sin(nx)} \right)^n
\left( \frac{e^{-x} x^{1/n}}{1 + e^{-x} n^{-1} \sin(nx)} \right)^n
= \frac{e^{-nx} x}{(1 + e^{-x} n^{-1} \sin(nx))^n}.
$$
With Bernoulli we get $(1 + e^{-x} n^{-1} \sin(nx))^n \geq 1 + e^{-x} \sin(nx)$. So
$$ \frac{e^{-nx} x}{(1 + e^{-x} n^{-1} \sin(nx))^n}
\leq \frac{e^{-nx} x}{1 + e^{-x} \sin(nx)}
= \frac{e^{-n} x}{e^{x} + \sin(nx)}.$$
But I don't see how I can estimate this last quantity further. Can anybody give me a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stated inequality is false.  That is, the inequality $$\frac{nx^{\frac{1}{n}}}{ne^{x}+\sin\left(nx\right)}\leq\frac{1}{e^{x}}$$  does not hold for integers $n$ and $x\in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$.  To see why, notice that the left hand side is

$$\frac{x^{\frac{1}{n}}}{e^{x}+\frac{\sin\left(nx\right)}{n}}\geq\frac{x^{\frac{1}{n}}}{e^{x}+1}$$ $$\geq\frac{x^{\frac{1}{n}}}{2e^{x}}=\frac{x^{\frac{1}{n}}}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{e^{x}}.$$  For your inequality to hold, we would need $$\frac{x^\frac{1}{n}}{2}\leq 1$$ for all  $x\in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$, which is absurd.

Comment: Thank you. I misunderstood the dominated convergence theorem. I thought I needed to estimate the sequence on its own limit, but apparently any integrable function will do... :)

Answer (score 1):

Take $x=\pi/2$ and $n=2$ for a counterexample.